# SwiftUI Firestore Data Isn't Getting Displayed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this file here:

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FirestoreManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var devices: [Device] = []
    
    
    func fetchAllDevicesForUser(uid: String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
       
            db.collection("users/" + uid + "/devices").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No docs")
                    self.devices = [Device(name: "You currently don't have any devices.", id: "", type: DeviceType.none)]
                    return;
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.devices = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Device in
                        let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let type = data["type"] as? DeviceType ?? DeviceType.none
                        print(name)
                        return Device(name: name, id: queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID, type: type)
                    }
                }

            }
       
    }

}
```

the `name` does get printed correctly.
I have this file for the models:

```swift
import Foundation

enum DeviceType {
    case drone
    case none
}

struct Device: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let id: String
    let type: DeviceType
}
```

And this is my view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var authModel: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject var firestoreManager = FirestoreManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Welcome,")
                .font(.title)
            Text(authModel.user?.displayName ?? "User")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            Button("Add Device") {
                
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            Text("Devices")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
            List(firestoreManager.devices) {
                device in
                Text(device.name)
            }
            .onAppear() {
                self.firestoreManager.fetchAllDevicesForUser(uid: authModel.user!.uid)
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Home")
        
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

This problem is that the list is empty.
How can I fix this?
This is my first time with SwiftUI.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject` where you own the object -- use `@StateObject`

Comment: @jnpdx I made that change but that didn't work, something else must also be wrong.

Comment: You also shouldn't have `List` inside of a `ScrollView` -- a `List` already scrolls. It's possible it's collapsing its height because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- Use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` where the `ObservableObject` is owned
- `List` shouldn't be embedded in a `ScrollView`, since they both scroll -- this will lead to odd sizing behavior.